# 2 Classes, extend same class, can this be simplified?

Tags: java

First Class

```
Class A extends C
    @Override
    public String doSomething(){
        String a = "ABC".replace("B", "");
        return a;
}
```

Second Class

```
Class B extends C
    @Override
    public String doSomething(){
        String a = "CBA".replace("B", "");
        return a;
}
```

Is there a way to put this code into the super class and not have to have two nearly identical methods?

Comment: In this particular case, we need some more detail about what's in those methods; as it is, you would just replace each with `return "AC"` or `return "CA"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an abstract method in your base class, which will return the "start string" in your `doSomething()` method. You can call it inside the `doSomething()` method and do your replacements. The base class will be looking like this:

```
abstract class C
{
    abstract String getStartString();

    public String doSomething()
    {
        String str = this.getStartString();
        str = str.replace("B", "");
        return str;
    }
}
```

New sub classes have to implement the `getStartString()` method to generate the starting point (like `"ABC"` or `"CBA"`), but the programming logic to use it (and to do the replacement) is in the base class and only written once.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can implement a single method as :

```
public String doSomethingInCommon(String input){
    return input.replace("B", "");
}
```

That is what, your methods are actually doing. Of course, these can then be used with different *'input'* from different classes.